# Kubernetes: Cannot access mongodb replicaset service from a different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, replicaset

If there's something wrong with the way I phrased the question please tell, so I can be better next time or edit the question.

**What I did.**

Use rancher to create an cluster with Amazon EKS.

Deployed a nodejs app in 'default' namespace.

Installed MongoDB replicaset from the rancher app catalog with default settings.

- Service/Deployment name is mongodb-replicaset
- namespace is also mongodb-replicaset

When I use `mongodb://mongodb-replicaset:27017/tradeit_system?replicaSet=rs` as connection string.

I get the error.

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb-replicaset-:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb-replicaset mongodb-replicaset:27017]

Then I read in [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services) that to access a service in a different namespace you need to also specify the namespace along with the service name.

So I did this `mongodb://mongodb-replicaset.mongodb-replicaset:27017/tradeit_system?replicaSet=rss` as the connection url I get the error.

> MongoError: no primary found in replicaset or invalid replica set name

Comment: Note: In the tag description for kubernetes it suggests asking in [serverfault.se] or [superuser.se]

Comment: The last error suggests you've successfully connected to MongoDB, but the database cluster isn't configured correctly.  So you've solved your "connect to the service in another namespace" problem already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have to include the namespace in the hoststring if if you want to access it as well as reference the cluster domain, which you aren't doing.

To quote from [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id)

> The domain managed by this Service takes the form: $(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local, where “cluster.local” is the cluster domain.

so in your case, your pod DNS would be written as:

`mongodb-replicaset.mongodb-replicaset.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: This didn't work still `mongodb://mongodb-replicaset.mongodb-replicaset.svc.cluster.local:27017/tradeit_system?replicaSet=rs` Error : MongoError: no primary found in replicaset or invalid replica set name

Comment: In one place you have the replicaset as "rs" the other as "rss", the default is "rs0", do you know which of these it actually is?

Comment: mstorkson, thank you. That solved it!. The default replicaset name was set to rs0.